# create unique error message for list item ng- repeat angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an HTML page to display users posts. 
when getting the posts from the server I'm using ng-repeat to display them in a list, with a positive or nagative vote button, in the following way:

```
<div ng-repeat = "z in posts">
    {{z.content}}
    {{z.uploadTime}}
    {{z.uploadingUserNickname}}
    {{z.rating}}                            
<br>                            
<button name= "PositiveVoteBtn" ng-click = "PositiveVote(z)"> Positive vote to Answer</button>
<button name= "NegativeVoteBtn" ng-click = "NegativeAnswerVote(z)"> Negative Vote to Answer</button></div>
```

when the user votes for an answer, the server validates that the user does not vote for his own post, and that he did not voted twice.

I would like to display an error message next to the voting buttons if the vote is not valid, but I'm not sure how to identify the error message with ng-repeat (in order to change it in the controller): if I'll use {{error}} in ng-repeat- than the message would be displayed next to all of the posts.. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a suggestion, Disable the up-vote button if the user already voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an optional error field to the post , `z.error`. If the post has an error, then display it: `<div ng-show="z.error">{{z.error}}</div>`.

Comment: I've tried to add the above code, but it doesn't work: maybe I don't set the value properly, how do I set this variable from js ? js code gets the post as a parameter to a function: